# Point Free with lists in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, lambda, functional-programming, pointfree

So I saw the algorithm for point free conversion here [Point Free problems in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596285/point-free-problems-in-haskell)
but what if the points i'd like to remove are hiding in a list? For instance a line like the following?

```
AllNsTill n x = [n,2*n..x]
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that although lists already have enough functions defined that you can probably make any use of lists point-free, for a general data type there is no way to turn arbitrary pattern matching into point-free form, without first defining new functions for the purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That [sequence syntax desugars](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#sect3.10) to a call of the [`enumFromThenTo` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:enumFromThenTo):

```
allNsTill n x = [n,2*n..x]
-->
allNsTill n x = enumFromThenTo n (2*n) x
```

Now you can convert that to point-free syntax (if you really want). I'd argue though that it gets really unreadable:

```
allNsTill = (*2) >>= flip enumFromThenTo
```

Comment: Follow up: list-comprehensions can be rewritten in terms of `map` and `filter`.

Comment: @Bakuriu, don't you mean `concatMap`?

Comment: @dfeuer: depends on what comprehension you use :-) Of course both `map` and `filter` can be implemented using `concatMap`.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, I see. Okay. Yeah no I wouldn't want to change it to point free, but was very curious about how it'd be done. Much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Tshimanga: Maybe `allNsTill n = enumFromThenTo n (2*n)` is a reasonable compromise

Comment: @Bergi Yeah that looks pretty good. I was hopeful that there might be a sugared version of the points free form because `lengthOf n = [1..n]` changes to `lengthOf = [1..id]`... oh well