# Filter a list of tuples by fst

Tags: haskell, currying

What I'm trying to do is not really solve a problem, but more to learn how to write Haskell code that composes/utilizes basic functions to do it.

I have a function that takes a list of tuples (String, Int) and a String, and returns a tuple whose fst matches the given String.
This was fairly easy to do with filter and lambda, but what I want to do now, is remove the rightmost argument, ie. I want to refactor the function to be a composition of partially applied functions that'll do the same functionality.

Original code was:

```
getstat :: Player -> String -> Stat
getstat p n = head $ filter (\(n', v) -> n' == n) $ stats p
```

New code is:

```
getstat :: Player -> String -> Stat
getstat p = head . (flip filter $ stats p) . cmpfst
    where cmpfst = (==) . fst . (flip (,)) 0  -- Wrong :-\
```

The idea is to flip the filter and partially apply by giving in the list of tuples (stats p) and then compose cmpfst.
cmpfst should be String -> (String, Int) -> Bool so that when String argument is applied, it becomes a -> Bool which is good for the filter to pass in tuples, but as you can see - I have problems composing (==) so that only fst's of given tuples are compared.

P.S. I know that the first code is likely cleaner; the point of this task was not to write clean code but to learn how to solve the problem through composition.

Edit:

I understand well that asking for a head on an possibly empty list is a bad programming that'll result in a crash. Like one earlier poster mentioned, it is very simply and elegantly resolved with Maybe monad - a task I've done before and am familiar with.

What I'd like the focus to be on, is how to make cmpfst composed primarily of basic functions.
So far, the furthest I got is this:

```
getstat :: Player -> String -> Stat
getstat p = head . (flip filter $ stats p) . (\n' -> (==(fst n')) . fst) . (flip (,)) 0
```

I can't get rid of the (a -> Bool) lambda by composing and partially applying around (==). This signals, to me, that I either don't understand what I'm doing, or it's impossible using (==) operator in the way I imagined.

Furthermore, unless there's no exact solution, I'll accept signature-change solution as correct one. I'd like not to change the signature of the function simply because its a mental exercise for me, not a production code.

Comment: See [Point Free problems in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596285/point-free-problems-in-haskell/29596461#29596461), which provides an algorithm for converting a function to point-free style.

Comment: This is gold. Thank you!

Comment: Using your link, I managed to redo the original code into:
`getstat p = head . (flip filter $ stats p) . (\n (n', v) -> n' == n)`

Its ugly, but it is what I asked for. I wonder if there's a nicer composition that can eliminate the anon f.

Comment: What if there is no such stat? Boom! Error message! Do you know all the types of stats in advance? If so, you should probably use records instead of lists to hold them.

Comment: @dfeuer I am trying to keep data outside of the code, but I'd still like to hear about your idea. Would you please elaborate a little, I am not sure what do you mean by 'records'.

Comment: @JohnZ Something like `data BatterStats = BatterStats { rbi :: Rational, batAvg :: Double, ...}`, or whatever. A player can `Maybe` have batting stats, pitching stats, etc. There are various ways to structure it, depending on your needs and preferences. This sort of thing is much harder to do if you aren't willing to encode in your program at least *some* information about what stats you intend to track.

Comment: @dfeuer That's a very good point, and I wonder if I need to additionally rearrange my thinking process too. Maybe I carry too much 'baggage' in form of experience from imperative languages and need to re-learn to model software using more concrete constructions rather than keeping everything in data.
I'll think about your suggestion, thank you for bringing it up!

Comment: This particular distinction is more "static vs. dynamic" than "OO vs. functional", but it's something to think about. Haskell generally has a "culture" of structuring data to reflect what should be known about it by any given point in a program. Sometimes, you're lucky enough to know all the "keys" at compile time, and to know they should all be present.

Comment: Sometimes, you know all the keys but some can acceptably be absent. Sometimes (more advanced techniques, often not worth the trouble of encoding in types) you know everything once the program loads its configuration. Sometimes you're in the wild west and just need to use good error handling everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you reached

```
getstat p = head . (flip filter $ stats p) . (\n (n', v) -> n' == n)
```

> I wonder if there's a nicer composition that can eliminate the anon f.

Well, here it is

```
\n (n', v) -> n' == n
-- for convenience, we flip the ==
\n (n', v) -> n == n'
-- prefix notation
\n (n', v) -> (==) n n'
-- let's remove pattern matching over (n', v)
\n (n', v) -> (==) n $ fst (n', v)
\n x -> (==) n $ fst x
-- composition, eta
\n -> (==) n . fst
-- prefix
\n -> (.) ((==) n) fst
-- composition
\n -> ((.) . (==) $ n) fst
-- let's force the application to be of the form (f n (g n))
\n -> ((.) . (==) $ n) (const fst $ n)
-- exploit f <*> g = \n -> f n (g n)   -- AKA the S combinator
((.) . (==)) <*> (const fst)
-- remove unneeded parentheses
(.) . (==) <*> const fst
```

Removing `p` is left as an exercise.

Comment: This is art! If you check my main post edit, I think I was on the right path, but as soon as you reach Applicative operator, it goes right over my head. I know where to focus my study now.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If I were writing this function, I'd probably have given it this type signature:

```
getstat :: String -> Player -> Stat
```

This makes it easy to eta-reduce the definition to

```
getstat n = head . filter ((== n) . fst) . stats
```

Comment: That's interesting! I actually made it Player -> String -> Stat because I (incorrectly) assumed it'll make eta-reduce simpler (tnx for the correct term too).
It made sense to me, from logical standpoint, that partially applying a player would happen seldom, in comparison to partially applying with a stat.