# composition and partial application on haskell

Tags: haskell, composition, partial-application

I'm trying to do this: Define the function `evenOutcome`, which applying it with an `n` number and an `m` number, returns true if the result of raising `n` to the number `m` is even.
Note: Solve it using partial application and composition.

I did this: `evenOutcome m n = even (m ^ n)`, which works, but does not satisfy the composition and partial application tasks.
To satisfy the tasks I did this: `evenOutcome = even.(^)`,
which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Hint: `m ^ n` is the same as `(^) m n`.

Comment: @duplode      (^) m n  means the same  in prefix notation, but I don't understand how to use it in this case,  because I need to use partial application

Comment: I mentioned the prefix syntax because it makes it a bit easier to see how you are supposed to partially apply `(^)`.

Comment: @duplode   I tried to do :                                                                                                                     ` evenOutcome = even.(^) `    because I thought it as prefix notation.

Comment: In your attempt, you are composing functions (with `(.)`), but you aren't doing any partial application.

Comment: There is an [algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596285/point-free-problems-in-haskell/29596461#29596461) for making any function normally defined pointfree.

Comment: @duplode       you were right.  New version: evenOutcome n = even.(^n)

Comment: Yup, that's the idea. Note that your new version isn't exactly equivalent to the original one due to the order of the arguments -- for that, you want `evenOutcome m = even . (m ^)`.

Comment: @duplode Thanks, I understood the problem