# How can I make a combinator with this type signature?

Tags: haskell, combinators, tacit-programming

I've been trying to make a combinator with this type signature:

```
(a -> b -> c) -> (c -> d -> e) -> a -> b -> d -> e
```

I've been through [Data.Aviary.Birds](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary) and all the tacit programming help sites that I can find, but to no avail. Also, if there's a general algorithm to make these, it would be greatly appreciated but not necessary.

Comment: For "a general algorithm to make these", see [luqui's answer to *Point Free problems in Haskell*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29596461/2751851).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our definition will start like this:

```
foo :: (a -> b -> c) -> (c -> d -> e) -> a -> b -> d -> e
foo abc cde a b d = e
```

Now let's fill in the missing bits.

We need an `e`; the only way to get that is by applying the second function to a `c` and `d`.

```
e = cde c d
```

We are already given a `d`, but we need a `c`. How do we get a `c`? By applying the first function to an `a` and a `b`.

```
c = abc a b
```

We are given both of these, so we're done.

```
foo :: (a -> b -> c) -> (c -> d -> e) -> a -> b -> d -> e
foo abc cde a b d = e
  where
    e = cde c d
    c = abc a b
```

**We might stop here.** This is a perfectly good definition.

---

But if we want to try to make it more terse, let's start by substituting the definition of `e`

```
foo abc cde a b d = cde c d
  where
    c = abc a b
```

and then of `c`

```
foo abc cde a b d = cde (abc a b) d
```

We immediately see that we can eta reduce to remove the `d`.

```
foo abc cde a b = cde (abc a b)
```

**The type is now slightly more general.** `d -> e` has collapsed into one type variable, since it can actually be anything.

```
foo :: (a -> b -> c) -> (c -> de) -> a -> b -> de
```

We can now see in the aviary that our combinator is actually the blackbird, flipped.

```
blackbird :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d

foo :: (a -> b -> c) -> (c -> de) -> a -> b -> de
foo = flip blackbird
```

And indeed if we look at the source for the blackbird, it looks much like what we have written.

```
-- | B1 combinator - blackbird - specs 'oo'.
blackbird :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
blackbird f g x y = f (g x y)
```

---

**Can we go more point-free?** We might consider uncurrying `abc`

```
foo abc cde a b = cde (uncurry abc (a, b))
```

rewriting this nesting with function composition

```
foo abc cde a b = (cde . uncurry abc) (a, b)
```

and currying back again

```
foo abc cde a b = curry (cde . uncurry abc) a b
```

And now we can chop off two more parameters.

```
foo abc cde = curry (cde . uncurry abc)
```

**We should definitely stop here.** But what if we now flip the arguments

```
foo = flip $ \cde abc -> curry (cde . uncurry abc)
```

rewrite the right half to make it point-free

```
foo = flip $ \cde abc -> (curry . ((cde .) . uncurry)) abc
```

and eta reduce once more

```
foo = flip $ \cde -> curry . ((cde .) . uncurry)
```

and take one final ridiculous step

```
foo = flip $ (curry .) . (. uncurry) . (.)
```

We are now point-free!

Comment: `flip ((.) . (.))` ?

Comment: `flip ((.) . (.) . flip)`. (I eventually went with `(f .) . g` for a modicum of readability.) Thanks for the extensive answer!

Comment: @APerson, from a practical standpoint, `(f .) . g` is pretty informative. You can write it `rmap f . g`, where `rmap` is from `Data.Profunctor` and `(.)` is from `Control.Category`. This generalizes the type somewhat more. You can even use `o` from `Data.Semigroupoid` instead of `(.)` for another little generality boost.

Comment: Er... I think I got that a little confused. I shouldn't write when sleepy. I'll check the details in the morning.

Answer (score 6):

There's a really easy way: cheat. Let's start by finding out what function we want. For this, we go to [Djinn](http://www.hedonisticlearning.com/djinn/). Type in

```
f :: (a -> b -> c) -> (c -> d -> e) -> a -> b -> d -> e
```

and it comes back with

```
f a b c d = b (a c d)
```

Nice. Now head over to [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io). Paste in the definition from Djinn, and it says

```
f = flip ((.) . (.))
```

Done.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about that tool!